# Password protected link gives 404 in Django and Nginx

Tags: django, nginx

I want to password-protect a single page of my Django website (I don't want to use Django's authentication system, which I'm using already for other parts of my website; this is an unrelated one-off) by adding this to my nginx.conf:

```
location /myprivatepage {
auth_basic "Private page";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}
```

And putting user and password in `/etc/nginx/.htpasswd`. When I point my browser to /myprivatepage the browser asks indeed for user and password. Once successfully authenticated, I get a 404 error:

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.14.2
```

If I comment the lines above I can reach the page as guest correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't obvious to you that with this location your request is not going to the django backend and tried to be served by some static file `/your/root/myprivatepage` or `/your/root/myprivatepage/index.html` etc? If you want to use this authentication mechanism you should duplicate all the backend configuration within this location (`proxy_pass` or `uwsgi_pass` or whatever you are using).

Comment: Thanks - no, it wasn't obvious before you pointing it out (still learning, bit by bit). Before you commented I found this: https://serverfault.com/questions/917226/nginx-basic-auth-is-set-up-and-working-but-all-protected-pages-return-404 which pointed me towards the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. I needed to repeat these two lines:

```
include proxy_params;
proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
```

(which are already within the `/ location instruction`) within the `/myprivatepage location` instruction.